# How do I call a function every whatever seconds in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Not sure why this is so hard to do in Javascript... Slightly frustrating LOL

Here's one of the ways I've tried to do it:

```
function rotateDavid() {
  $("#david").css({
    'transform' : 'rotate(90deg)'
  });
  setTimeout(rotateDavid, 10000);
};
rotateDavid();
```

It will do it once but doesn't repeat... I dunno...

Comment: setInterval(function, 1000); Call function at every 1 second.

Comment: well you would need to change the number of degrees.... You set it to the same thing every time.

Comment: @Ajay the code above is fine with the timeout....

Comment: oh god please stop i'm getting dizzy

Comment: @Don'tPanic Those answers wouldn't solve his real problem, which is due to css transforms being absolute not relative.

Comment: @Don'tPanic And you clearly did not actually look at the question and see you are wrong. People on here jump to conclusions way to fast around here....

Comment: @Don'tPanic OP thought he had an issue with looping. And it ends up, he did not. He did not understand the problem with the code. Within minutes I pointed him to his actual problem. It is amazing!

Comment: @Don'tPanic He has done his research, as the code actually calls a function every 10 seconds perfectly. The question should really be amended to ask 'How do I make an element rotate with css and timeouts' or something. There may be duplicates of that.

Comment: @epascarello Oh good it's a recursive loop... Thanks...

Comment: OK, I'm just having a bad day. Sorry everyone. I'm going to delete my comments and un-downvote. Sorry @topher!

Comment: Why not use a css animation, no JavaScript necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not how you are calling the function. This way is actually preferred over setInterval in some cases.

The issue you have is that setting the Css to 90degrees is not changing it over and over. You are setting it to the same degree value every time.

You need to update the angle on every iteration. So in this case you want to add 90 to it.

```js
var rotation = 0;
function rotateDavid() {
  rotation += 1
  $("#david").css({
    'transform' : 'rotate(' + (90 * rotation) + 'deg)'
  });
  setTimeout(rotateDavid, 1000);
};
rotateDavid();
```

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="david">Hi</div>
```

You can also use a mod operator to keep the number from getting huge.

```
'transform' : 'rotate(' + (90 * (rotation%4)) + 'deg)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method, actually, is called every `10s`. You can check it if you add a log to the console inside the method. However, you was setting the css property always to the same value, so you won't see any visual effect. A possible fix is shown on next example:

```js
function rotateDavid(rot)
{
  $("#david").css({
    'transform': `rotate(${rot}deg)`
  });

  rot = rot + 90 >= 360 ? 0 : rot + 90;
  setTimeout(() => rotateDavid(rot), 5000);
};

rotateDavid(0);
```

```css
#david {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="david">David</div>
```

Even more, you can get similar functionality using `setInterval()`:

```js
function rotateDavid(rot)
{
  $("#david").css({
    'transform': `rotate(${rot}deg)`
  });
};

var rot = 90;
setInterval(
  () => {rotateDavid(rot); rot = rot + 90 >= 360 ? 0 : rot + 90;},
  5000
);
```

```css
#david {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="david">David</div>
```